# How can I specify the gestures to be used for zooming or panning in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

On Two finger trackpad up or down, I want to disable zoom but instead enable panning. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Disable user zooming in Cytoscape.js and build your own gesture that pans the graph on browser `wheel` events.